# Call jquery tab activate function not on a click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I'm working with a page that loads up a lot of data. I'm working to make it more user friendly, right now, it just loads up everything, I would like to make it load nothing but the frames then make it load the info when a specific tab is opened. This works. However I also want to leverage jquery's ability to automatically open a tab using the url hash fragment. This also works, except that the on select function defined below is not called in this case.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    show: function(event, ui) {
        $('#tabs ul li a').click(function () {

            var sSelectedTab = updateUrl($(this).attr('href'));
            // Get the current vertical scroll position
            var iCurrentWindowPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
            location.hash = sSelectedTab;
            // Put the vertical scrolled position back to where it was
            $(window).scrollTop(iCurrentWindowPosition);
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {

            switch (ui.index) {

                case 1:

                    // Corresponds to "Drives" tab
                    createSpinAnimation("#tabs");
                    $.post("ajax_api.php",
                        {

                            sAction: "loadData1"
                        },
                        function(data) {
                            //do things with data here
                        }
                    );
                    break;
             }
     }
});
```

I have tried clicking the tab programatically (`$('#tabs a[href="' + location.hash + '"]').click()`), however since the tab is already selected and active, the click is ignored.
How can I call the `select:` function from outside the tab on click?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain what you're trying to accomplish, but I can give you a partial answer on how to call select from outside the tab internals.

```
$('#tabs').tabs("instance").select(null, {index: 0});
```

or

```
$('#tabs').tabs("select", null, {index: 0});
```

I thought this might help give you some insight into accessing any of the ui functions in an object fashion.

A.